# AEM 6.2 How to change template of a page

Tags: aem

I have created live copy of a page branch from sample website, inside my website. I was just trying to update the template so that I can create a local copy of the template used with original page and then change the UI. I can see the property with the **cq:template** and **sling:resourceType** as component name in development environment(CRXDE Lite). Can anyone suggest if we can update the property to change the template and component or if there any other way to change the template.

Comment: did you mean `sling:resourceType` instead of `sling:resourcename` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update `cq:template` and `sling:resourceType` on `page/jcr:content` node with corresponding new values and it would effectively change the template of page.

you might run into errors if code on new page component is expecting a different content than what is currently under your jcr:content.

ps- I dont know what your use case is but this would be  very crude approach and should be avoided.

Comment: Use case is same which is mentioned in the question.